# Why new created default dynamic view is full of non archived files and folder?

Tags: clearcase

All the VOBs are BASE Clearcase.

When I create a new dynamic default Clearcase view as my_view, the elements archived in Clearcase are well in folder:

```
/views/my_view/vobs/vob_001/... archived elements
```

But, I don't know why there is exist plenty of non archived files and folder there:

```
/views/my_view/... plenty of non archived files and folders
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [dynamic view storage folder](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_mvfs/about_storage_dirs_dyn.htm) will keep versioned and non-versioned (and non-archived) files in it:

> For dynamic views, this directory is used to keep track of which versions are checked out to your view and to store view-private objects.

That is why, by the way, [View storage maintenance for dynamic views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_maint_view_stg.htm) does advise:

> Removal of unneeded view-private objects.
>   As with any other isolated work area, a view’s private storage area tends to accumulate some unneeded files: temporary files, text-editor backup files, excerpts from mail messages and source files, and so on.